Removing obsolete shortcuts in ~/.local/bin
When installing a package with pip install --user, it will create shortcuts/launchers in ~/.local/bin for any executable entry points in that package.
After upgrading Python via the distro's package manager, these packages, installed in ~/.local/lib/pythonX.YY, effectively disappear from the system, because the newer Python version will not pick them up. The corresponding shortcuts thus end up broken, unless the package is reinstalled under the new Python version.
I am looking for an automated way of cleaning up these obsolete shortcuts.

You can easily do that with a script.
First determine current Python version; then define directories by setting variables for the local binary and library directories, and finally find and remove obsolete shortcuts. Like this:
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current Python version
current_python_version=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(f'{sys.version_info.major}.{sys.version_info.minor}')")

# Define the local bin and lib directories
local_bin="$HOME/.local/bin"
local_lib="$HOME/.local/lib"

# Find obsolete shortcuts
for shortcut in "$local_bin"/*; do
    # Check if the shortcut is a symlink or executable script
    if [ -L "$shortcut" ] || [ -x "$shortcut" ]; then
        # Check if the target of the shortcut exists and is an executable
        target=$(readlink -f "$shortcut")
        if [[ "$target" == "$local_lib/python"* ]] && [[ "$target" != *"$current_python_version"* ]]; then
            echo "Removing obsolete shortcut: $shortcut"
            rm -f "$shortcut"
        fi
    fi
done

echo "Cleanup completed."

Good luck!

On my computers, I have crontab execute it @daily to improve my Python reliability after upgrades.

In my case, these files are not symbolic links, but rather "stub" Python scripts that try to import the actual package and hand over control to it.

Instead of editing the answer, I provided an additional solution due to the similarity of the issue.

Unlike my other answer, if the files are not symbolic links, but stubs, you can still easily fix it with a script.
Determine current Python version and store it in the current_python_version variable.Then define directories by setting the local_bin and local_lib variables to point to the local binary and library directories.
Then the is_python_stub function checks if the first line of the file starts with #!/usr/bin/env python, indicating it is a Python script.
The references_obsolete_python function checks if the script contains references to Python versions other than the current one.
Finally remove the obsolete shortcuts by iterating over all files in ~/.local/bin, checks if they are Python stubs referencing obsolete Python versions, and removes them if they are.
Like this:
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current Python version
current_python_version=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(f'{sys.version_info.major}.{sys.version_info.minor}')")

# Define the local bin and lib directories
local_bin="$HOME/.local/bin"
local_lib="$HOME/.local/lib"

# Function to check if the script is a Python stub
is_python_stub() {
    head -n 1 "$1" | grep -q "^#\!/usr/bin/env python"
}

# Function to check if the script references an obsolete Python version
references_obsolete_python() {
    grep -q -E "python[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" "$1" | grep -v "python$current_python_version"
}

# Find obsolete shortcuts
for shortcut in "$local_bin"/*; do
    # Check if the shortcut is a stub Python script
    if [ -f "$shortcut" ] && is_python_stub "$shortcut" && references_obsolete_python "$shortcut"; then
        echo "Removing obsolete shortcut: $shortcut"
        rm -f "$shortcut"
    fi
done

echo "Cleanup completed."

Good luck!
